# how to merge two For Loop

Tags: batch, loop, for

```
if(sObjectType == 'Order') {
        List<order__c> list_Order = new List<order__c>();
        // todo=merge both the for Loop
        for(SObject obj : s_object){
            order__c order  = (order__c)obj;
            list_Order.add(order);
             System.debug('--list_Order---'+list_Order);
        }
            for(Order__c obj_Order : list_order){
                set_nonDeleteId.add(obj_Order.Account_Holder__r.account__c);
                System.debug('--set_nonDeleteId---'+set_nonDeleteId);
        }
```

how to merge these two for loop to a single for loop

Comment: This seems like it should be very straightforward. What have you tried? What conceptual issue are you running into here?

Comment: in this code, there was no running issue but I want a single loop

Comment: That's not what I was asking. I'm asking about what you've tried so far to make this just have a single loop. From my perspective, this question right now sounds like a "do my work for me" request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set set_nonDeleteId =  new Set();

```
if(sObjectType == 'Order') {
        for(SObject obj : s_object){
            order__c order  = (order__c)obj;
            if(order != null){
                set_nonDeleteId.add(order.Account_Holder__r.account__c);
            }
        }
    }
    System.debug('--set_nonDeleteId---'+set_nonDeleteId);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Its working

Comment: Downvoted for code dump with no explanation.